# Automatic wake from suspend when power restored to laptop

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management, chromebook, wakeup

I'm using a Chromebook with Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS installed as an embedded system of sorts.  I've figured out how to have it automatically suspend when disconnected from power by adjusting the power manager settings.

But I would like to find a way to have it automatically wake when power is restored.

If it isn't possible to detect that event and wake up, I also have a powered FTDI USB serial interface connected that could generate an event to wake on, but it doesn't appear in the list of `/proc/acpi/wakeup` devices.

Note that when I run `upower -d`, I see things that could be potential triggers.  For example, device `/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC` has a `line-power/online` field (set to `yes` when plugged in).  Device `/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0` has an `on-battery` field (set to `no` when plugged in).

I'm open to switching to a scenario where I automatically shutdown when the battery is low, if it's possible to configure the computer to automatically turn on when power is restored.  I've seen it do that on occasion, but not reliably.

If it matters, I'm using a [John Lewis](https://johnlewis.ie/) ROM which boots Ubuntu through GRUB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further research, I found that I could get the desired behavior with my setup.

I went into the Power Settings and configured battery power as:

- Suspend when inactive for: Don't suspend
- When power is critically low: Power off
- When the lid is closed: Do nothing

Likewise, when plugged in it's set to not suspend when inactive or the lid is closed.

To test, I unplugged the Chromebook and waited for the battery to get critically low and power off (overnight).  When I reconnected power the next day, it automatically booted and all was good.

My previous tests had failed because I was shutting the system down manually, instead of having Ubuntu do it.

I was unable to find a solution using suspend and wake.  It could potentially work with additional USB hardware with an ability to send a keyboard event to wake the Chromebook up when power is connected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making several assumptions here, since I don't know exactly what hardware you're using. *Generally* speaking, there is an option in a computer's BIOS called **Power Loss Restart** or **AC Power Loss Restart** (see [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/bios-beginners,1126-8.html) for a little more info). If that function is not enabled, try enabling it.

Comment: It's an Acer Chromebook C720, so I don't have the traditional type of BIOS as shown in your link.  I'll investigate where there are settings for that BIOS -- from what I've seen previously, the only option is to select a boot device.  I can check with John Lewis, creator of the BIOS, to see if it's something he knows about.  It would be nice if Ubuntu could configure the ACPI hardware for power loss restart.

Comment: To me it sounds like you're on the right track now, at least. Getting in touch with the developer is a great idea. I'm looking forward to any updates.